# Laravel Livewire Detect Overlapping Time

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am currently trying to build a conflict detection feature for Schedule Manager. Schedules with conflicts will have red background.

The problem is with **overlapping time intervals** which I would also like to be flag as conflict.

Based on the table below the two schedules should be mark red since 7:00-8:30 is between 7:00-10:30.

This is how I constructed the table with sample data. Restructuring the table for now is not an option.

### room|  day |  c_time|

### 105 | M-W   | 7:00-8:30|

### 105 |W  |   7:00-10:30  |

Controller

```
        foreach($sched->get() as $keyG=>$pG) 
        {
          $pGx=explode("-",$pG->day);

          foreach($pGx as $xKey=>$xx)
          { 
              $classDayTime[]=array('s_id'=>$pG->id,'s_day_time'=>$pGx[$xKey].$pG->c_time.$pG->room);
          }
        }                $conflictRoom=array_count_values(array_column($classDayTime,'s_day_time'));
```

Blade

```
foreach($sched->paginate(20) as $key=>$p) 
        { 
          
          $res = explode("-",str_replace([")","("],"",$p->c_time));
                ?>
                
                
               
                <tr class="
                     <?php 
                $e=explode("-",$p->day);
              
                              foreach($e as $dKey=>$d)
                              { 
                                
                                  $dt=$d.$p->c_time.$p->room;
                                  
                              foreach($$conflictRoom as $ky=>$k)
                            
                              {
                         
                                  if($dt==$ky)
                                  {
                                    if($dt==$ky)
                                  
                                         
                                      
                                          if($k != 1)
                                          {
                                           
                                    
                                            echo "divide-y dark:divide-white text-black text-s text-center bg-red-400";  
                                          }
                        
                                          else
                                          
                                          echo " ";  

                                  }     

                              }
                              }
                             
                            ?>
                ">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take the values like init_time and end_time after explode the string provided

```
$explode_first = explode("-", "7:00-8:30");
$first_init_time = $explode_first[0]; // "7:00" 
$first_end_time = $explode_first[1]; // "8:30" 

$explode_eval = explode("-", "7:00-10:30");
$eval_init_time = $explode_eval[0]; // "7:00" 
$eval_end_time = $explode_eval[1]; // "10:30" 

if($eval_init_time < $first_end_time && $eval_end_time > $first_init_time)
   // it's overlaping
```

And for sure you must cast the values to time objects before comparing them.

Comment: Thanks @Prospero now I am getting somewhere.

Comment: Can you please show me where can I integrate that in my existing code.